# Odd behavior with ParseFloat when my string is too long

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5, parsefloat

I was making a calculator (something like excel in javascript) and I have found a strange behavior with ParseFloat.

```
parseFloat(999999999999999)  //999999999999999

parseFloat(9999999999999999) //10000000000000000

parseFloat(9999999999999899) //9999999999999900
```

Is there a limit with parseFloat function in javascript? Following [ECMA Standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.2.3) there is no issue about this.

Comment: https://randomascii.files.wordpress.com/2012/03/image6.png

Comment: Never use `parseFloat` on a number. It's a string function!

Answer (score 1):

`Float` is not an endless container. Consider this example:

```
console.log(0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3) // Prints... FALSE!
```

Or, another case:

```
console.log(99999999999999999999999999999999999) // Prints 1e+35
```

...while `1e+35` is just `1` with `35` zeroes. Original number (`9999...`) is so large and precise that `JS` starts cutting `lower digits` to store at least something - the source is too big to save in `float`.

This actually happens because of internal `float` conversions made by **JavaScript engine** and the philosophy of `float` type is that **higher digits are more important that lower**.

Your case is somewhat similar. This is because floating point type `accuracy` depends on its value length. So, If your value is too big or too small, you will lose precision for lower digits.

Thus you should never trust `float` and never compare it with other values using '==' of '===' - it may be anything.